# Can PHP invoke Java objects?

Tags: java, php, interop

Right now, I am in the process of learning PHP and I have some experience in Java.  In some languages, you have the ability to use libraries written in one language and the use it's objects in another.  For example, you can invoke objects written in C++ in VB using COM/COM+.  **How well does this idea translate in regard to PHP and Java?  Is this even a good idea?**

Keep in mind I am NOT talking JavaScript.

Comment: I guess your example about C/C++ with VB shows that you're talking about Java and not JavaScript.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify because I see that PHP and JavaScript seem to compliment each other and the term "Java" gets thrown around loosely in context to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, with PHP 5 the two current options seem to be use [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/) as your PHP web server.  ZSCE supports Java connectivity when the [Java Bridge](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-Community-Edition/zend-server-community-edition.htm#working_with_the_java_bridge.htm) is enabled.

The other option appears to be [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) which is a SourceForge project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, PHP can invoke the Java objects..
For instance, you can do like this:

```
 <?php 
    $fp = new Java("java.io.File", "test.txt");
    if($fp->exists())
    { 
      echo "The file ". $fp->getAbsolutePath() . " is ". $fp->length() . " bytes"  
    } 
    else 
    { 
       echo "The file " . $fp->getAbsolutePath() . " does not exist";
    }
 ?>
```

Note :As PHP doesn't come with Java support turned on by default, you'll need to recompile it to enable this support. You can do this by adding the "--with-java" compile-time parameter to the PHP "configure" script.

For more, you can read [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Using-PHP-with-Java/1/).

As above extension doesn't exist for PHP5, you can use [JavaBridge](http://files.zend.com/help/previous-version/Zend-Studio-i5-5/java_bridge.htm) of Zend server and [PJB(PHP/Java Bridge)](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)

Comment: The `--with-java` compile option was only available in PHP 4 and was removed in PHP 5.  The PECL repo it was moved to is now dead as well.  [Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/java.installation.php).